# Unable to display table data with offset by using custom controller pagination in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm very new to SFDC and now I'm trying to implement pagination using offset values. But I'm getting this error: **Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: visualforce.el.VisualforceArrayList**

I've built with the help of this tutorial link

Here is my complete code for the same. Please have a look

**Pagination.vfp**

```
<apex:page controller="NewContactPaginationCtrl" action="{!getContacts}" >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Table With Pagination">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.id}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.email}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons">
                <apex:form>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="< Previous" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>        
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value="Forward >" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**NewContactPaginationCtrl.apxc**

```
public class NewContactPaginationCtrl {
    Private Integer counter=0;
    private integer list_size=5;
    public integer total_size;
    
    public NewContactPaginationCtrl(){
        total_size = [select count() from Contact];
    }
    
   
    
    public Contact[] getContacts(){
        try {
            Contact[] contacts = [
                SELECT 
                id,
                name,
                email FROM
                Contact
                LIMIT :list_size
                OFFSET :counter
            ];
            return contacts;
        } catch(QueryException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public PageReference Previous(){
        counter -= list_size;
        return null;
    }
    
     public PageReference Next(){
        counter += list_size;
        return null;
    }
    
    public Boolean getDisablePrevious() {
        if(counter>0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public Boolean getDisableNext(){
        if(counter+list_size < total_size){
            return false;
        }else{
           return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<apex:page controller="NewContactPaginationCtrl" action="{!getContacts}" >
```

This is attempting to tell Visualforce that you want to (possibly) redirect using the action parameter. This is incorrect, and shouldn't be there.

```
<apex:page controller="NewContactPaginationCtrl">
```

---

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList}" var="c">
```

cList doesn't exist. It should be contacts:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
```

A getX method can be bound to an attribute, and the get is removed. This is called a [getter method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm).

---

The comparison operators already return a true/false value, so you don't have to. For example:

```
public Boolean getDisableNext(){
  return counter+list_size >= total_size;
}
```

---

You should look at the [ApexPages.StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm). It provides all the same functionality you have here, but supports up to 10,000 rows (your code would be limited to 2000 plus page size, as OFFSET has a limit of 2000).

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked! I learnt so much from you. Appreciated your help :-)